# Get query result (ActiveRecord Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

model:

```
def self.auth(username, password)
    user = Users.where(:username => username).where(:password => password).first
    user
end
```

controller:

```
  def auth
    user = Users.auth("username", "password")
    render :text => user
  end
```

Result is nil. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is your model name really is `Users`?

Comment: @Pavan, yes, I tried return a string in model method auth and it works.

Comment: But according to rules the model name should always singular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Using the `model method(auth)` in the `controller` like this

```
def auth1
    user = auth(username,password)
    render :text => user
  end
```

**Note:** Your model should be **`singular(User)`**.Currently you have **`Users`**,which is against the **`Rails Convention`** and it might cause problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
model:

def self.auth(username, password)
    user = Users.where(:username => username, :password => password).first
    user
end

controller:

  def auth
    user = Users.auth(username, password)
    render :text => user
  end
```

Comment: Whats is the name of your model ?

Comment: class Users < ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: then from where you will send (username, password) to auth method.

Comment: Means when user will submit the username and password the which method will call.